# Java: Printing LinkedList without square brackets?

Tags: java, collections

This is a fairly simple question. When you print out a LinkedList, like so:

```
System.out.println(list);
```

It prints it out, surrounding the list in square brackets like this:

```
[thing 1, thing 2, thing 3]
```

Is there a way I can print it out without the square brackets?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes - iterate the list and print it (with comma after each, but the last element). However, there are utils to help:

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
String result = Joiner.on(", ").join(list);
```

[commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
String result = StringUtils.join(list, ", ");
```

And one note: don't rely on the `.toString()` method of any object. It is not meant for displaying the object to users, or to be used as a predefined format - it is meant mainly for debugging purposes.

Comment: This one needs +2 for the utilities and the `toString()` bit.

Comment: What is the import for StringUtils?

Answer (score 5):

A quick-and-dirty answer is:

```
String s = list.toString();
System.out.println(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));
```

Comment: Since you included the "quick and dirty" disclaimer, I won't downvote your answer. That said, this is exactly the type of stuff we should be *discouraging* other developers from doing.

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass `LinkedList` and override it's `toString()` method, but that seems a little excessive. Instead, iterate over it's elements and construct a `String` with either a `StringBuilder`, or a `StringBuffer`(if concurrency is an issue).

**Note:**
I suggest you don't follow the answer provided by [@Sean Owen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854084/java-printing-linkedlist-without-square-brackets/7854121#7854121), since that's implementation-dependent and therefore, fragile.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default implementation of the toString() on LinkedList.  You could extend LinkedList to provide your own implementation or use composition and just implement the java.util.List interface.

```
public class MyLinkedList<E> implements List<E>
{
   private final List<E> delegate;

   public MyLinkedList(List<E> list)
   {
      delegate = list;
   }

   /**
    * @return see overriden class or implemented interface
    * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
    */
   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      return "My special toString() method";
   }

   // implement rest of the java.util.List interface
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified from `AbstractCollection.java`:

```
   /*
    * @return a string representation of a collection
    */
   public static final String collectionToString(Collection c) {
       Iterator<E> it = c.iterator();
       if (! it.hasNext())
           return "";

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for (;;) {
           E e = it.next();
           sb.append(e == c ? "(this Collection)" : e);
           if (! it.hasNext())
               return sb.toString();
           sb.append(',').append(' ');
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StrBuilder builder = new StrBuilder(); // apache commons lang.
for (Object object : yourList)
{
  builder.appendSeperator(", ");
  builder.append(object.toString());
}

System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the String returned by the `.toString()` method and remove the first and last character, or make your own list class and override the `.toString()` method to iterate through the list and print the elements without the brackets. Or you can do it as an anonymous class like:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>() {
    public String toString() {
        // Custom To String Stuff Here
    }
};
```

And of course I'm too slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you're into **groovy**, there's no need to import anything, just do:

```
list = ["thing 1", "thing 2", "thing 3"]    
println list.collect { i -> "$i" }.join(', ')
```

> *thing 1, thing 2, thing 3*

---

Same goes with Map collection:

```
map = [I:"James Bond", love:"rock N roll", id:"007"]
println map.collect { k,v -> "$k = $v" }.join('\n')
```

> *I = James Bond*
>
> *love = rock N roll*
>
> *id = 007*