# Making an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, hierarchy

I have made a class called Fish:

```
public class  Fish {

    private String species;
    private int size;

    //Constructor
    public Fish(int x, String s) {
        size = x;
        species = s;
    }

    public String getSpecies() { return species; }

    public int getSize() { return size; }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("A %dcm %s", size, species);
    }
}
```

And I have also started to make a class called pond that is meant to have an attribute called 'fish' that holds an array of Fish objects. I am unsure of how to do this. Here is my attempt so far. I am

```
public class Pond {
    private int capacity;
    private Object[] fish; //This is what I am trying to initialize. list of Fish. 
    private int numFish;

    //Capacity Constructor 
    public Pond(int n, int c) {
        n = numFish;
        c = capacity; 
    }

    public int getNumFish() { return numFish; }

    public boolean isFull() {
        boolean isFull = false;
        if (numFish >= capacity) {
            isFull = true;
        }
        else {
            isFull = false;
        }
        return isFull;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Pond with %d fish", numFish);
    }

    public void add(Fish aFish) {
        if (numFish <= capacity) {
            numFish += 1;
            fish.add Fish;
        }
        else {
            numFish += 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html. BTW, I can't see any question. Just two notes: if it's an array of fishes, it should be of type `Fish[]`, and be named `fishes` (array ==> multiple fishes ==> plral form)

Comment: @JBNizet fish is also plural for fish, I think (not a native speaker here). But yes, in this context fishes is probably better.

Comment: @peter.petrov: thanks. I learnt something today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ArrayList` instead of `Array` since an ArrayList can grow according to requirements.

Take a look at this code.Should help you:

```
public class Fish {
String name;


public Fish(String name) {

    this.name=name; 

}

public String toString() {
    return name;
}
}
```

And then:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pond {

ArrayList<Fish> fishInPond = new ArrayList<>();


public void addFish(Fish e) {

    fishInPond.add(e);
}

public void showFishes() {
    for (int i= 0; i<fishInPond.size();i++) {
        fishInPond.get(i);
   } 
    System.out.println("Fishes in my pond: " + fishInPond);
}


    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Pond myPond = new Pond();
        myPond.addFish(new Fish("Tilapia"));
        myPond.addFish(new Fish("cat fish"));

        myPond.showFishes();
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This helped me a lot. Now would there be any way to remove the square brackets surrounding the listed fish? For example instead of displaying [Tilapia, cat fish] it would display Tilapia, cat fish ?

Comment: And maybe perhaps make each fish have it's own line when printed out?

Comment: There are a few ways you can do this, i suggest you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854084/java-printing-linkedlist-without-square-brackets)

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

`private Object[] fish;`

as follows:

`private Fish[] fish;`

i.e. these are fishes and not just any
kinds of objects (they not mammals e.g.).

Answer (score 1):

In the `Pond` constructor you're assigning private fields to constructor arguments. I think it should be the other way around:

```
public Pond(final int n, final int c) {
    numFish = n;
    capacity = c;
}
```

A side note: declaring `Pond` constructor arguments `final` would [prevent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4930124/1240162) these kind of error at compile time.

Also, if you want to expand `fish` array at runtime then `array` is not the best choice of the container type. `ArrayList<Fish>` is a better choice as it can expand at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Following is invalid -

```
fish.add aFish;
```

with arrays you do

```
fish[numFish] = aFish; //increment numFish after this
```

You also need to initialize your array

```
fish = new Fish[capacity];
```

in your constructor.